# coldfusion variables within cftry do not persist

Tags: coldfusion, try-catch, cfml

I have a `<cftry` outside of a `<cfmail` tag. Within the `<cftry` a variable x is set. The variable x does not survive past the `</cftry>` .

```
<cfoutput>
<cftry>
<cfmail

          from     = "user@example.org"  
          to       = "other@example.org"          
          password = "something"
          username = "user@example.org"     
          server   = "localhost"                            
          replyto  = "user@example.org"
          subject  = "try-catch"               
          type     = "html"   >   

  <cfset x = 'abc'>

  this is to test email
  </cfmail>
  success

  <cfcatch>
  <cfoutput> email failed </cfoutput>
  </cfcatch
</cftry>


<!--- there is no variable x --->
x is #x#
</cfoutput>
```

I would like to find some way to pick up the value of x after the end of the `<cftry`.  I've tried setting it with diferrent scopes inside the `<cftry`

```
<cfset register.x = 'abc'>  or even
<cfset session.x = 'abc'>
```

But neither of those preserves x outside of the `<cftry>`.  Can someone suggest a way to preserve x beyond the `</cftry>`?

Comment: Did the success message display?

Comment: When there is success x is preserved.  But when it fails x is not preserved.  However, in the real case I'm running a loop, and I don't want it to stop or crash if I get an error.

Comment: Side note, be sure to change your password right away, since it's already archived.

Comment: What version of CF are you using? This would indicate that your code failed before `x` was set, so it's not available. Try setting `x` at the top of your try, and it will probably work (unless your `x` is what's failing). Or set `x` outside of the `try/catch` block.

Comment: Does `x` have anything to do with what you are trying to do in the `try/catch`? If not, I'd put it outside anyway. Especially if you want to use it later.

Comment: Shawn x is holding the place of an extensive computation within the <cfmail tag, so I can't move it out, unless I recompute the whole thing.  However, I'm not worried about the "x", I'm worried about a correct "to = ".

Comment: Ageax -- thx, I will change the password.

Comment: If you are doing computations in the `cfmail` tag, and it fails, it's context will no longer be available because of the failure. Do the computation outside of the `cfmail` tag, and then put `try/catch` around both. They're both essentially different errors. It might actually have been failing on that computation, so that wouldn't have been available anyway.

Comment: Shawn, I originally had the computation outside it, and the problem was that sending the email messed up the formatting of "x", which is actually a report.  So as far as i can tell, I can't get that computation out of there.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to be make more example code available to see, so that we can tackle the full problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have a misconception about exception handling. Code within `try` is only fully executed if there is no exception. As soon as an exception occurs within `try`, the execution is stopped and jumps to the `catch`.

## Example 1

```
<cftry>

    <cfset x = "everything is ok">

    <cfcatch>
        <cfset x = "an exception occured">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

This will always output `everything is ok`, because the code within `try` can be executed without causing an exception.

## Example 2

```
<cftry>

    <cfthrow message="I fail you!">

    <cfset x = "everything is ok">

    <cfcatch>
        <cfset x = "an exception occured">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

This will always output `an exception occured`, because the code within `try` is only executed to the point where an exception is thrown (we are doing it on purpose here with `<cfthrow>`).

## Example 3

```
<cftry>

    <cfset x = "everything is ok">

    <cfthrow message="I fail you!">

    <cfcatch>
        <cfset x = "an exception occured">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

This will still output `an exception occured`. Although the `<cfset x = "everything is ok">` statement was properly executed and set the variable `x`, we are still jumping to the `catch` due to throwing an exception.

## Example 4 (this is your issue!)

```
<cftry>

    <cfthrow message="I fail you!">

    <cfset x = "everything is ok">

    <cfcatch>
        <!--- we are doing nothing --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

This will throw a runtime error telling you that `x` is undefined. Why? Because the statement declaring `x` is never reached due to encountering an exception. And the catch doesn't introduce the variable either.

## Long story short

Your `<cfmail>` is causing an exception and `<cfset x = 'abc'>` is never reached.

## The Fix

Proper error handling means to meaningfullly handle caught exceptions. Don't `<cfoutput> email failed </cfoutput>` your way out of it and act like you don't care. Log the exception (there is [`<cflog>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflog.html) for that) and monitor it. For debugging purposes, you can use [`<cfrethrow>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfrethrow.html) within `<cfcatch>` to keep the original exception instead of silently absorbing the real reason for the error.

Comment: Actually, move `cfset x` above the `cfthrow` and it will "return" `x`. It doesn't appear to roll back things done in the `try` block. It will only pass off to the `catch` after the failure occurs.

Comment: In Example 3, `x` is set in the `cftry` code, and then overwritten in the `cfcatch`. That's why it's good to keep `try/catch` blocks as minimalist as possible.

Comment: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=bc82f4a1-3257-4479-b4c8-908078ad9579/8a6f7024-585f-4f72-aaef-f4d6f20cb872/0f1bd03a-2c71-489b-960d-25f2c38e5979.cfm

Comment: The examples are just showcasing the behavior of try/catch. Never work with variables that are declared in an "inner context" (`try` block content) and expect them to live in an "outer context" (code after `try` block). OP said he can only assign `x` after doing something in `<cfmail>`, so declaring `x` beforehand is only solving the runtime error, not the actual problem itself.

Comment: Agreed. That's why `try/catch` should be as minimal as possible. Variables in the `try` should essentially be considered "throw-aways" unless that variable is also handled in the `catch`. Personally, I never realized that all of the `try` wasn't rolled back when it went to `catch`. But it will apparently keep things done before the failure. :-/

Comment: Wow. That's amazing. I've learnt something new today. I thought everything was ignored, except for code inside the cfcatch block, if an error occurs anywhere inside the cftry block...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson That's what I thought too. That could cause some unexpected behaviors if you change something in a `cftry` and think it rolled back because of the error caught in `cfcatch`, kinda like a transaction is "supposed" to do. But a `try/catch` isn't really a transaction. It's error handling. Chalk it up to "Things I never thought about but good to know." :-)

Comment: This clarifies things.  I'm glad to understand better how try/catch works.

Comment: For all those who have been helping with this, I found a workaround.  Alex' explanation will be most useful in avoiding this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: Regarding the comment `Never work with variables that are declared in an "inner context"` eventually declare your variables you need after the action that may fail before the `cftry`-tag. I usually set a boolean variable to false before cftry. The last statement in the try block is to set this variable to true to know I've been successfull. I've seen code wrapped a query in a try/catch block trying to use that query afterwards - fails every once in a while.

Comment: @Shawn I very rarely use cftry, because it essentially prevents errors from being thrown. I only use it, when I know about the errors it might throw and am happy for the code to continue to execute.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Depends! You can test if a file exists (or not). Accessing the file for a read (or write) operation might fail anyways, because another application has an exclusive lock. There definitely are cases where try/catch is recommended. You of course have to take care for reporting/logging the error as CF does not write to `exception.log` if there was a catch clause. `cfrethrow` might be a solution in selectd cases.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Usually, you wouldn't want to display an error to your user, so make sure you catch that error somehow and only give your user some sort of 500 "Uh oh" error, at the most. Catch it to give your devs more info so they can fix it. Error messages can give away a lot of information about your application and system that can be used in less than polite ways. :-/

Comment: And personally, I just prefer to write bug-free code so I don't have to worry  about this stuff. :-)

Comment: @Shawn That's correct. When cftry is used too liberally, it can often hide bugs. This is why I only use cftry around one or two lines of code, something like cffile action=write. Sometimes this operation fails, but not because there is a bug or an error in the way the code is written. 90% of our code should be exposed, so that any bugs can be fixed:)

Comment: @CharlesRobertson I think we might be thinking along the same lines. But any sort of `try/catch` is pretty much _meant_ to hide bugs from users and pass the error off to whatever can handle it. Liberally using error handling isn't a bad thing. It can make things harder in Dev, but it's a must in Production. Code should only be exposed to the development team. Users (even if they are Devs) should never see code from your application. Using `try/catch` allows this to be done gracefully.

Comment: @Shawn. I tend to use the application.cfc onError handler in production. This will redirect the user to a custom error page & send the devs an e-mail containing the error.